# I'm struggling to concatenate a string to a function

Tags: python, python-3.x

This is my code. Solution #1:

```
def age():
    input('Age: ')

def friends():
    print("John" + age)
```

Expected outcome:

```
John13
```

Actual outcome #1:

```
TypeError: can only concatenate str (not "function") to str
```

Solution #2:

```
    def age():
        input('Age: ')

    def friend():
        print("John" + age())
```

Solution outcome #2:

```
TypeError: can only concatenate str (not "NoneType") to str
```

How can I concatenate my function `age` (`age` is an `input()` function declaration) to a string or strings? The `age` function is an `input()` and I want to add it to the appropriate name or string.

Comment: you need to return the value which you can concatenate: `return input('Age: ')` from the `age()` method.

Comment: The `age()` function doesn't _return_ anything, therefore it returns None by default.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add a return statement to your function `age`, for example:

```
def age():
       agein = input(...)
       return agein
```

Answer (score 0):

`age()` doesn't do anything with the input, it just throws it away immediately. You need to actually return the value.

Also, there's little point in creating a method that does nothing but call another method. Why not just call `input(...)` "directly"?

Also, your first solution does not concatenate the string returned by `age` - without the `()`, you try to append *the age() method itself* to the string, which doesn't make sense.

Comment: Good day thank you everyone for your help my code now works perfectly fine.

Comment: @ZaydenMichealJames Glad we could help. Can you [accept the answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) that was the most helpful to you? (Could be either of the answers, depending on which one helped you fix it).

Answer (score 0):

As you know, the variable `age` as you've defined it is a function, not a string.

So your question boils down to:

> How can we extract the actual data we want -- in this case, a string representing an age -- from
> our function?

In other words,

> How can we make our function "return" the data we want?

Simple! There is a construct in Python (and just about every other programming language) that does exactly this!

It is called a `return` statement. It "returns" a value -- any value you want -- from a function, which simply means that your code outside the function may use that value.

For example:

```
def age():
    age = input('Age: ')  
    return age          // We can now use this value outside the function!
```

You can use it like so:

```
def friends():
    johns_age = age()   // calling the age function and assigning its returned value
    print("John is " + johns_age)
```

If you found this answer helpful, I suggest you read a beginner-friendly Python book (such as the free *Automate the Boring Stuff with Python*), as you'll learn much faster that way than asking questions on this rather strict and unfriendly site.